# GetAndroidConfig using firebase management service C# .NET returning Google.GoogleApiException: Parameter validation failed for "parent"

Tags: c#, firebase, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-api

After creating a web app config in firebase using the c# library, I wanted to get the configuration file, but I am getting error :- Google.GoogleApiException: Parameter validation failed for "parent" : The value did not match the regular expression ^projects/[^/]+$ ..... as shown below , how do I fix this issue?

```
     public static WebAppConfig GetWebAppConfig()
   {
        var listWeb = _firebaseManagementService.Projects.WebApps.List("projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId + "/webApps").Execute();
        return _firebaseManagementService.Projects.WebApps.GetConfig("projects/-/webApps/" + listWeb.Apps[0].AppId + "/config").Execute();
   }
```

Edited -> The error that displays in my terminal is as shown below

Unhandled exception. The service firebase has thrown an exception.
No HttpStatusCode was specified.
No error details were specified.
Google.GoogleApiException: Parameter validation failed for "parent" : The value did not match the regular expression ^projects/[^/]+$
at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.AddParameters(RequestBuilder requestBuilder, ParameterCollection inputParameters) at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.CreateBuilder()
at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.CreateRequest(Nullable`1 overrideGZipEnabled)
at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.ExecuteUnparsedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on this line,

```
var listWeb = _firebaseManagementService.Projects.WebApps.List("projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId + "/webApps").Execute();
```

And removing /webApps resolved the issue

```
var listWeb = _firebaseManagementService.Projects.WebApps.List("projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId).Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your config path in the second call seems to be malformed.

`return _firebaseManagementService.Projects.WebApps.GetConfig("projects/-/webApps/" + listWeb.Apps[0].AppId + "/config").Execute();`

Let's imagine that `listWeb.Apps[0].AppId` contains `"foo-app-id"`.
That would result in the path parameter for the `GetConfig` call to be set as `"projects/-/webApps/foo-app-id/config"`. This doesn't seem like a valid path for Google Cloud Platform (the dash after `"projects/"` is what's off).

I'd guess you want to use your `CloudManager.ProjectId` variable value in this path too:

`return _firebaseManagementService.Projects.WebApps.GetConfig("projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId + "/webApps/" + listWeb.Apps[0].AppId + "/config").Execute();`

Comment: Actually Philip,  I am having the error on the line above the return statement.              
var listWeb = _firebaseManagementService.Projects.WebApps.List("projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId + "/webApps").Execute();
I don't know what is off in this line, but I have tested the return statement  with CloudManager.ProjectId replaced, and the error persists.